# What is the difference "FTP on the Go" and "FTP on the Go Pro" for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, software-recommendation, applications, ios

What is the difference "FTP on the Go" and "FTP on the Go Pro" for iOS? and which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the main difference is that the *Pro* version is universal. That means it will work on iPhone and iPad whereas the *normal* version only works on iPhone.

From the [website](http://www.ftponthego.com/information.php):

> - Optimized for iPad, but also runs perfectly on an iPhone or iPod touch.
> - View many files at once in the tabbed viewer. This lets you easily copy between files, compare, etc.
> - Switch between browsing and full-screen viewing or editing with just a tap.
> - Quick-scrollers let you scroll through files or folders super fast.

Comment: But really, everything is on their website which took me 5 seconds to find with a Google search...